# Substituting command echo with "echo -e" on linux

Tags: linux, shell, echo, alias, subshell

I have a shell program that has content like this

```
!#/bin/bash

echo \\n program
```

Once I run this program on a platform other than Linux it recognizes the special character and gives the output as

```
(newline)
program
```

When the same program runs on Linux, the echo command needs the "-e" option.
Now I don't want to change each occurrence of echo with "echo -e" in my file explicitly because then this will start creating issues on other platforms. So I want to do a conditional compilation like

```
set SYSTEM="uname -s"

#if ($SYSTEM == Linux)
set echo="echo -e"
#endif
```

but this does not work because using the set or export command, I need to replace all occurrences of echo with $echo, which I don't want to do.
Again setting aliases does not solve this issue as i need echo to be replaced with "echo -e" even in subshell.

Is there any other way around with which I can substitute echo with "echo -e" only for Linux platform?

Comment: Is switching to using `printf` for portability an option?

Comment: Do you have a bash script, or do you really have a sh script? If you're sure it's always bash, echo is a builtin, and it can be configured to work the same way on all systems. If it could be run by other shells too, consider `printf` as per Wrikken's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of [`BASH_ENV`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) and a function we can do:

```
bash-3.2$ export BASH_ENV=$HOME/always-source
bash-3.2$ cat $HOME/always-source 
echo() {
    command echo -e "$@"
}

bash-3.2$ cat runme.bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "\nHello World $1\n"

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    $0 child
fi
```

And an invocation:

```
bash-3.2$ ./runme.bash 

Hello World 


Hello World child
```

Wrapping this in a bash test (linux & mac os x):

```
if [[ $(uname -s) = Linux ]] || [[ $(uname -s) = Darwin ]]; then
    export BASH_ENV=$HOME/always-source
fi
```

Comment: you put this command in some script and try running it in subshell, it won't work.

Comment: By adding it to your `.bashrc` it will be sourced in all `bash` scripts.

Comment: It will source it only in new shell, not in subshells.

Comment: I've changed the answer to use `BASH_ENV` and a function, rather than an alias (which doesn't seem to work in a non-interactive environment)

Answer (score 0):

I belive you are looking for an alias.

The syntax in bash would be
`alias echo='echo -e';`

Comment: They should. A subshell is exactly like any other shell.

Comment: @gbtimmon...
then please try it out once.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you don't want to change the echo calls, but how do you think about using `echo $'\nhello\n'` instead of `echo -e`?

Answer (score 0):

Define an alias in your shell:

```
alias echo="echo -e";
```

then source your script:

```
source ./<script1>
```

By doing this, your script will not create a subshell and use the variables of the parent shell. Also, variables which you define in your script will exist even after termination of your script.

For invoking other scripts in script1.sh, use source:

```
source ./<script2>
```

Comment: my script invoke other script which uses again uses echo command.

Comment: Thnx Upasna,
I know this and few other way around, but i want to go conditional compilation way to fix this up.

Comment: @Manish But can't you just put the alias inside of the conditional?

Comment: @Ternary
That is not alias, i am using set command inside condition.